Server Sent Error Handling in Godot Game Engine - Laravel Backend
I am making HTTP requests to a Laravel-backend server using the HTTPRequest. It works well, but the problem is in displaying the error message I get from Backend.
For example, I submit a Form that requires a name and password, but the user submits only with email. The server sends an error with the message in it as password is required.
I can get the error response code, but I couldn't find the error message in Godot.
func _http_request_completed(result, response_code, _headers, body):
    var data = body.get_string_from_utf8().strip_edges()
    if result != HTTPRequest.RESULT_SUCCESS:
        push_error("An error occurred in the HTTP request.")

    if response_code >= 400:
        print(data) ## this prints an HTML document
        var json = JSON.parse_string(data)
        print("json format error", json) ## this prints <null>
        print("request error with response code: ", response_code) ## getting the response code
        return

    var json = JSON.parse_string(data)
    if json:
        request_completed_with_data.emit(json)


How do I get that error message that the server sent? If I use the browser to call API, in the network tab, I can see the error messsage, but in Godot, I couldn't find.
Is there any other way to handle the API calls for Godot Engine?
Thanks. Any help will be appreciated!

what html does your body contain on error? Is your error message in it? The json convert will logically not work if you let it parse pure html

I cannot confirm it. Printing the whole html doesn’t properly fit on console.

Make the http request with postman or print the string line by line. Just so you know what the endpoint actually returns, since it definitly does not just return a simple string message

In postman it returns html doc, instead of just message. But in web app if I use axios I can get the actual error message, how does axios getting that but I cant.

Axios has a request config parameter called responseType  which defaults to JSON. It could be that, this parameter changes the accept header of the request. You could look at the request in wireshark, or try to send a Accept Header in postman which only allows application/json. Maybe this changes the content-type the server sends to you
